# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01843: not a valid month error - date format conversion issue

Tags: sql, date, jsp

I'm having a strange issue here with a query from which I'm trying to pull data queried by start and end date parameters.

I'm conducting the following.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
String preparedQuery = "SELECT ID, FULNAME, FRMEMAIL,    LOCATION,TYPE1,TYPE2,BORROWER_NAME,LOAN_NUM,TIME_REQ
FROM FORM_REDUCVU WHERE to_date(TIME_REQ,'yyyy-mm-dd') >= ?  AND to_date (TIME_REQ,'yyyy-mm-dd') <= ? ORDER BY ID DESC";
java.util.Date util_StartDate = sdf.parse( request.getParameter("time_req_date") );
java.sql.Date timreq_datevar1 = new java.sql.Date( util_StartDate.getTime() );
java.util.Date util_EndDate = sdf.parse( request.getParameter("time_req_date2") );
java.sql.Date timreq_datevar2 = new java.sql.Date( util_EndDate.getTime() );
out.println("datestamp java time vals "+timreq_datevar1 + " " + timreq_datevar2);
PreparedStatement prepstmt = connection.prepareStatement(preparedQuery);
prepstmt.setDate(1, timreq_datevar1);
prepstmt.setDate(2, timreq_datevar2);
```

And the out.print values will give something like 2018-10-09 and 2019-02-20.
This does match the date picker selections I'm making, which are in mm/dd/yyyy format, i.e. 10/09/2018 and 02/20/2019.

Now the above returns no errors in the log, but no data either. But I did have the SQL query as  " 
    `WHERE to_datechar(TIME_REQ,'mm/dd/yyyy') >= ? AND to_char(TIME_REQ,'mm/dd/yyyy') <= ?`

When changing to this above, I get the error in the topic of not a valid month.

I would have thought the SimpleDateFormat class would have parsed the date to mm/dd/yyyy in pattern, but it seems to make the java.slq.Date object pattern hyphenated, like yyyy-mm-dd.

Am I not parsing it correctly? Or is this going to require a different class or package, like java.Time? I would thought this would work, but there has to be some small conversion method not working.
Bottom line - I'd really prefer to keep the jQuery date pickers with their mm/dd/yyyy formats in tact, and be able to query by these entries.
Any input regarding this is welcomed.
Thank you!

Comment: What data type is `TIME_REQ`?

Comment: it is a DATE field, in the Oracle 11 DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do **NOT** use `to_date()` on a column that is alread a DATE `to_date()` will convert the date to a varchar just to convert it back to a DATE which it was to begin with.

So your condition should be:

```
WHERE TIME_REQ >= ?  AND TIME_REQ <= ?
```

You are correctly using `setDate()` so Oracle performs a date to date comparison - there is no need to convert the date in the database to a string value.

Ideally you should use `java.time.LocalDate` and `setObject()` instead of `java.sql.Date` though (however not all Oracle driver versions support that)

Comment: OK, I was wondering about that, on the to_date method. Makes sense. I don't need to format the column (TIME_REQ) variable at all, huh? Ok. And so data being entered into the form in mm/dd/yyyy pattern can be correctly converted in this manner?

Comment: `time_req` is not a "variable" it is a column. your java code looks reasonable.

Comment: Thank you very much, horse_with_no_name! That solved it. And I suppose in my results set the date that is getting displayed is 2019-02-05, for example, which is java.sql.Date in nature. I assume if I want it prettied up to mm/dd/yyyy I just need to convert the Date object in the results set to a toString var to convert it?

Comment: I suppose I was overcomplicating things with those method conversions on it. I know Perl has one needed with its DBI module. Probably forgot it wasn't needed here. Ugh.